# WCSession "isComplicationEnabled" always returns false in iOS 15.4

Tags: ios, watchkit, watchconnectivity, apple-watch-complication

Since I've updated my test device (iPhone 12 mini) to the latest iOS version 15.4, the complications of my companion app on the watch (watchOS 8.5) do not receive any updates sent by the iOS app.

To reproduce the issue you need:

- An iOS app with an watchOS companion app and at least one active complication of this app. (I can provide you access to my TestFlight app.)
- The iOS app needs an active WCSession object to send update complication messages through "transferCurrentComplicationUserInfo:"
- If you check the isComplicationEnabeld property, it will always return false and therefore, the complication will not be updated.

This issues only occurs since the update to iOS 15.4. Previous versions did work well.

Here is my code to transfer the updated content for the complications...

```
if ([self.connectivityHandler.validSession isComplicationEnabled] &&
    self.connectivityHandler.validSession.remainingComplicationUserInfoTransfers > 0) {
    
    [self.connectivityHandler transferCurrentComplicationUserInfo:[self applicationContext]];
}
```

The `connectivityHandler` is a singleton object which handles the data transfer and holds the `WCSession` object (`validSession`).
It implements the `transferCurrentComplicationUserInfo` method to transfer the updated content for the complication.

Since iOS 15.4, the if clause above is always false due to the `isComplicationEnabled` check. Before it worked correctly.

I've already tried:

- Restarting devices: iPhone and watch
- Resetting watch

Anyone out there with the same issue and probably a solution?

Thank's for your support!

Comment: I do extensive watchOS development and I'm seeing this same behavior across multiple iOS apps in production that have a watchOS app. As far as I can tell it's a bug in iOS 15.4 and I would expect (hope) they will fix it in the next update.

Comment: Likewise, I am seeing this same issue with iOS 15.4 across a number of apps.

Comment: I am seeing this as well across all my test devices (and from a bunch of reports from users using my app in production).

Comment: I am still seeing this in the latest watchOS 8.6 & iOS 15.5 beta also. Are you all still seeing this @gohnjanotis @bmueller?

Comment: I have not tried it on any betas, but on the current production versions it's still happening.

Comment: Yes, I am still seeing in production as well. But given this isn't fixed in the latest beta is worrying.

Comment: I'm facing this issue too. Been getting A LOT of angry emails

Comment: Facing same issue.  But, there is no solution and fixes from apple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After first tests, Apple fixed it in iOS 15.5 and watchOS 8.6.